# iOS 5 ics (iCalendar) reading/parsing from webURL

Tags: objective-c, icalendar, eventkit, caldav

since iOS5 there ist the possibility to set an EKEventSource to EKSourceTypeCalDAV. Does anybody know if it is possible to receive events from a webUrl?
The webURL (lets take the google calendar as an example) returns the data in an ics file (iCalendar format)

I do not want the iCal-App to read the ics data, but to use the Eventkit framework to receive events within my own app.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It isn't possible to "set an EKEventSource to EKSourceTypeCalDAV". `EKSourceTypeCalDAV` just tells you that the particular `EKSource` is a CalDAV account, as opposed to one of the other types that can be configured in iOS. `sourceType` is a read-only property.

For clarity, an `EKSource` object is retrieved from an `EKEventStore`, which represents the iOS Calendar database. I'm not aware of an "`EKEventSource`".

EventKit isn't suitable for your purposes, it is for interacting with events contained within the iOS Calendar database (and app). But you can use this project to import external ics file,
[Ical for Objective-c](http://www.cybergarage.org/twiki/bin/view/Main/ICalForObjC)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, that's what I thought as well!
So I'll have to take libical and plug it into my project